# how to run this all combination of tree

Tags: haskell

would like to get all combinations of equations
for example , Or(And(A,B),C) , Or(A, And(B,C)) .... etc

then i find an example of tree seems near this idea, but it has compile error

```
main.hs:78:23:
    Couldn't match type `[]' with `Tree'
    Expected type: Tree ([a], [a])
      Actual type: [([a], [a])]
    In the return type of a call of `splits'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: (left, x : right) <- splits xs
    In the expression:
      do { (left, x : right) <- splits xs;
           Node <$> getAllTrees left <*> pure x <*> getAllTrees right }

main.hs:85:17:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type `Tree Integer'
    In the return type of a call of `getAllTrees'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `getAllTrees [1 .. 12]'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: mapM_ print $ getAllTrees [1 .. 12]
```

code:

```
module Main where
import Data.Foldable (toList)
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Sequence (Seq)
import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Control.Applicative

data Tree x
 = Null
 | Leaf x
 | Node (Tree x) x (Tree x)

splits xs = zip (inits xs) (tails xs)

getAllTrees :: [a] -> Tree a
getAllTrees [] = return Null
getAllTrees [x] = return $ Leaf x
getAllTrees xs = do
 (left, x : right) <- splits xs
 Node <$> getAllTrees left <*> pure x <*> getAllTrees right

main :: IO()
main = do 
  mapM_ print $ splits [1..12]
  mapM_ print comb
  mapM_ print $ getAllTrees [1..12]
```

Comment: What do you mean with `And` and `Or`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of your code has a couple of issues - mainly missing parts (`comp`) and that you complicated the tree to much (in my opinion).
For example the `Null` part seems strange and you did not really include the operations (`Or`, `And`) either.

But the idea with `splits` is promising!

I allowed myself to change your design a bit but this idea is still present.

First I changed the representation of those `And/Or`-Trees into:

```
data Operation
  = And
  | Or
    deriving Show

data Tree x
 = Leaf x
 | Node (Tree x) Operation (Tree x)
   deriving Show
```

As you can see it's a straight-forward rewrite - just included the operation instead of the element.

I did not change your first pattern-matches in `getAllTrees` much:

```
getAllTrees :: [a] -> [Tree a]
getAllTrees [] = []
getAllTrees [x] = return $ Leaf x
```

the empty list will just return the empty list, a single element list will yield a `Leaf`.

Next we have to decide what to do with those empty parts in `split` (like `([],everything)`) - because it would not really yield a valid tree (and get us into *troubles*) - but as you started using the **list-monad** and as it has [`guard`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:guard) available we can make use of it:

```
getAllTrees xs = do
  (left, right) <- splits xs
  guard $ not (null left) && not (null right)
```

instead of using Applicatives-syntax I find it easier to continue in the monads `do` style and recursively pull trees out of `getAllTrees` (and operators out of `[And,Or]`):

```
leftT <- getAllTrees left
rightT <- getAllTrees right
op <- [And, Or]
```

that leaves us with just returning the assembled `Node´ value:

```
return $ Node leftT op rightT
```

#### why the `guard`?

the problems arise form splits of the form `(fullList, [])`

If you look at the code you should see that you will call `getAllTrees` with the full-list over and over again recursively.

So if the guard is not there you will get the first couple of answers till you get the `(fullList, [])` split and then the output stops and you enter an infinite loop.

You might wonder why you don't see anything more - after all the recursive `getAllTrees` should reyield the ones you have already seen, and that is true - but then the `rightT <- getAllTrees right` will not yield anything as `right == []` here.

So of course

```
guard $ not (null right)
```

would be enough as it's no big deal if the left side is empty (as the very next line will deal with it, by pulling from an empty list) - but I liked the symmetry here.

### complete source

```
import Data.List (inits, tails)
import Control.Monad (guard)

data Operation
  = And
  | Or
    deriving Show

data Tree x
 = Leaf x
 | Node (Tree x) Operation (Tree x)
   deriving Show

splits :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splits xs = zip (inits xs) (tails xs)

getAllTrees :: [a] -> [Tree a]
getAllTrees [] = []
getAllTrees [x] = return $ Leaf x
getAllTrees xs = do
  (left, right) <- splits xs
  guard $ not (null left) && not (null right)
  leftT <- getAllTrees left
  rightT <- getAllTrees right
  op <- [And, Or]
  return $ Node leftT op rightT
```

#### example

this will return for example:

```
λ> getAllTrees [1..3]
[Node (Leaf 1) And (Node (Leaf 2) And (Leaf 3))
,Node (Leaf 1) Or (Node (Leaf 2) And (Leaf 3))
,Node (Leaf 1) And (Node (Leaf 2) Or (Leaf 3))
,Node (Leaf 1) Or (Node (Leaf 2) Or (Leaf 3))
,Node (Node (Leaf 1) And (Leaf 2)) And (Leaf 3)
,Node (Node (Leaf 1) And (Leaf 2)) Or (Leaf 3)
,Node (Node (Leaf 1) Or (Leaf 2)) And (Leaf 3)
,Node (Node (Leaf 1) Or (Leaf 2)) Or (Leaf 3)]
```

it should be easy to map this in any form you like

### the obvious generalization

By the way there is a obvious way to make these trees generic over the *connector* (`And`, `Or`) as well:

```
data Tree x y
 = Leaf x
 | Node (Tree x y) y (Tree x y)
   deriving Show

splits :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splits xs = zip (inits xs) (tails xs)

getAllTrees :: [b] -> [a] -> [Tree a b]
getAllTrees _ [] = []
getAllTrees _ [x] = return $ Leaf x
getAllTrees ys xs = do
  (left, right) <- splits xs
  guard $ not (null right)
  leftT <- getAllTrees ys left
  rightT <- getAllTrees ys right
  y <- ys
  return $ Node leftT y rightT
```

where you then had to call:

```
getAllTrees [And,Or] [1..3]
```

Comment: You are really expert to show this useful idea with haskell. Only haskell can do this complicated task in simple code.

Comment: the power of haskell is quite shocking.

Comment: thanks - but I'm not quite an expert - I'm most likely far further away from being an expert than your from whatever I am right now ;)

Comment: By the way: if this answers your question you should accept it ;) - if not I will happily try to help you out further

Comment: sorry for late tick it, as i am thinking another problem, for this problem, i think difficult to debug

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is quite in-depth. I would also like to give the minimal edit needed to make your code compile and run, so you can continue exploring on your own. There are only three things needed:

1. Fix the type signature on `getAllTrees` -- it returns `[Tree a]`, not `Tree a`.
2. Give a `Show` instance for trees. You can simply add `deriving Show` at the end of the declaration and GHC will write a suitable instance for you.
3. Decide what to do about `comb` (which isn't in scope here). Simply deleting the line that mentions it works fine.